# Why rails doesn't generate an object type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason any json created by my controller generates an array of json but not an object. I would like to know if its normal behavior? If its how can i obtain what i am looking for.

Here the controller

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @events }
  end
end
```

Now here what i actually get

```
[{"allday":true,"created_at":"2013-01-10T23:49:19Z","customer_id":1,"description":"A meeting tomorrow between Prime Minister","id":35}]
```

Now However I would like to see the object first like standard json has follow

```
{ "Article":{"allday":true,"created_at":"2013-01-10T23:49:19Z","customer_id":1,"description":"A meeting tomorrow between Prime Minister","id":35}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` to get the behavior you want globally. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json):

> The option `include_root_in_json` controls the top-level behavior of
>   `as_json`. If true (the default) `as_json` will emit a single root node
>   named after the object’s type. For example:
>
> ```
> user = User.find(1)
> user.as_json
> # => { "user": {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
> #               "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true} }
>
> ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
>
> user.as_json
> # => {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
> #     "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true}
> ```
>
> This behavior can also be achieved by setting the `:root` option to `false` as in:
>
> ```
> user = User.find(1)
> user.as_json(root: false)
> # =>  {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
> #      "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a ruby object or hash that mirrors the structure of the json object you want back and render it.

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @events.map { |e| { Article: e } } }
  end
end
```

This would give you something like

```
[{ "Article":{"allday":true,"created_at":"2013-01-10T23:49:19Z","customer_id":1,"description":"A meeting tomorrow between Prime Minister","id":35}}]
```

Comment: What about objects that belongs to them like an article can have comments?